# How to set admin user permission for root category?

Tags: admin, multistore, rules

I have three webstores.
Also I hired one manager for one webstore. So, I have three managers and three root categories in admin panel.

Let's name manager1, manager2, manager3 and webstore1, webstore2, webstore3.

I would like to hide root category from manager if he should't manage it.

Manager1 should see only own root category webstore1.
Manager2 should see only own root category webstore2.
Manager3 should see only own root category webstore3.

Is it possible to do without coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using Magento CE? This is not possible by default.

although I never used the extension [Aitoc Advanced Permissions](http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html) apparently does allow you to do this without the need for coding.

Comment: Yes, its Magento CE. Sorry, forgot to notice that.